# jquery.scrollTo.js isn't sliding horizontal after 5 divs

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a bit of a problem. I have a horizontal scroll that doesn't go horizontal if there are more than 5 divs.
I already found another post here on this site but it doesn't seem to apply to this one. can someone help me?

SO THE PROBLEM IS THAT AFTER THE 5TH DIV THE THEY ARE GOING VERTICAL AND THERE ARE SUPPOSED TO GO HORIZONTAL!

**The javascript files are:**

jquery.scrollTo.js

jquery-1.3.1.min.js
(if needed i can upload them)

**And the site of the last post:**

[jquery.scrollTo.js is not sliding more then 5 divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498154/jquery-scrollto-js-is-not-sliding-more-then-5-divs)

**The jsFiddle site (without jquery files!)**

http://jsfiddle.net/wuZYA/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Scroll Horizontally</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}

</script>

<style>

body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}

    #mask {
        width:500%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#eee;
    }

    .item {
        width:20%;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        background-color:#ddd;
    }


    .content {
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
        top:20%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:#aaa;
        position:relative;
    }

    .selected {
        background:#fff;
        font-weight:700;
    }

    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mask">

        <div id="item1" class="item">

            <a name="item1"></a>
            <div class="content">item1 
                <a href="#item1" class="panel">1</a> | 
                <a href="#item2" class="panel">2</a> | 
                <a href="#item3" class="panel">3</a> | 
                <a href="#item4" class="panel">4</a> | 
                <a href="#item5" class="panel">5</a> |
                <a href="#item6" class="panel">6</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="item2" class="item">
            <a name="item2"></a>
            <div class="content">item2 <a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="item3" class="item">
            <a name="item3"></a>
            <div class="content">item3 <a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="item4" class="item">
            <a name="item4"></a>
            <div class="content">item4 <a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="item5" class="item">
            <a name="item5"></a>
            <div class="content">item5 <a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="item6" class="item">
            <a name="item6"></a>
            <div class="content">item5 <a href="#item1" class="panel">back</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a JsFiddle, so that others can help you, [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: thx. but do you know a way to upload the jquery files? i doesnt work if i put everything in the "javascript" field. or i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Check out the dropdown box in the left and select `jQuery` and `onLoad` :)